# Convert SQL Server Stored Procedure into MY SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: software-recommendation, mysql, mysql-workbench

Any tools are available to Convert SQL Server Stored Procedure into MY SQL Stored Procedure.

We tried with some license tool  but only tables are created properly, but Stored Procedure are created with many issues.

We preferred tools which will create  Procedure with out issues.

Note:  We are ready to buy license software's.

Comment: "We are ready to buy license software's" we only can answer for Ubuntu and that tends to be open source and free. Here is a manual how to: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/03/mssql-to-mysql-stored-procedure/ and seeing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329643/convert-ms-sql-server-stored-procedure-to-mysql-query I would assume this question fits better on DBA ( http://dba.stackexchange.com/ ) since you need people with knowledge of both MSSQL and MYSQL. We only know about MSSQL ;)

Comment: Another how to: http://www.convert-in.com/mssql-to-mysql-stored-procedures.htm and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68697/converting-mssql-stored-procedure-to-mysql-syntax-error

Comment: Best I can come up with is http://www.sqlines.com/sql-server-to-mysql Paid software but they have a trial version: http://www.sqlines.com/download